# Use Every CSV file in a Folder

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to have this program use all of the CSV files inside of a folder. The folder is on my desktop, and it's called "Web_Scraper" (I'm on a mac btw).

This is how the code looks; what do I replace whatever is inside of the "enumerate" with (the 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, etc)?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import csv
import os

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.worksheets[0]

header_keys = []
for n, fName in 

enumerate(['3.csv','4.csv','5.csv','6.csv','7.csv','8.csv','9.csv','10.csv','11.csv','12.csv',]):
with open(fName) as fh:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=['header', 'data'], delimiter=',')
    if n == 0:
        for values in csv_reader:
```

I think I'm supposed to use something like os.listdir but I'm not exaclty sure what the syntax should be.

Comment: What is the problem btw? Please mention it

Comment: Btw, you can also use glob.glob('*.csv')

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I list all files of a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-do-i-list-all-files-of-a-directory)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all files in a directory with extension .txt in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3964681/find-all-files-in-a-directory-with-extension-txt-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the glob module

```
import glob

scraper_files = glob.glob('*.csv') //returns an array of filenames
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use something like below,

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

rootdir = 'xx/xx/x'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        if ('.csv' in Path.suffix)
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file, fieldnames=['header', 'data'], delimiter=',')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use os module

```
import os
os.listdir('~/Desktop/Web_Scraper') # Returns list of files or directory  names inside that dir
```

And you can apply filter on file name extension to filter out only csv files

Answer (score 0):

You can use python's inbuilt [`os`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) module.

```
import os
os.listdir("this-directory")  # returns list of files in this-directory
```

E.g.

```
import os
for file in os.listdir("."):  # reading from current directory, replace it with your directory.
   if file.endswith(".csv"):
      with open(file) as fh:
          csv_reader = csv.DictReader(fh, fieldnames=['header', 'data'], delimiter=',')
              if n == 0:
                  for values in csv_reader:
```

Hope it helps!